# JS get all URL parameters available for final form page

Tags: javascript, html, forms, url, url-parameters

I see a lot of ways and a number of them seem overly complicated.
i do plan on appending a program that will use these parameters to test based on the results.

But for now, I want a way to get all the URL parameters and post them using a p tag.

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question? You can get the search params of a URL with the `URL` constructor and accessing the `searchParams` property.

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');

const appendParams = (url) => {
    const params = Object.fromEntries(new URL(url).searchParams.entries());

    for (const key in params) {
        const p = document.createElement('p');
        p.textContent = `${key}: ${params[key]}`;
        div.appendChild(p);
    }
};

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    appendParams('https://hello.world?foo=bar&fizz=buzz&abc=123&hello=world');
});
```

```html
<div></div>
```